# OpenCSV: Method is returning null when reads the CSV

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I'm dusting off my knowledge in Java, after a long time without taking the language, and I'm using OpenCSV for Java. I wrote a method that reads a CSV file with the following structure:

```
id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,ip_address,date
1,Bear,Picker,bpicker0@wordpress.com,Bigender,33.63.86.239,20/06/2021
2,Emili,McEntee,emcentee1@sciencedirect.com,Bigender,163.127.107.66,03/08/2021
3,Bethena,Fortune,bfortune2@live.com,Genderqueer,52.250.33.22,22/04/2021
4,Mortie,Praten,mpraten3@google.nl,Genderfluid,181.3.231.237,09/07/2021
5,Nappy,Giabucci,ngiabucci4@unc.edu,Female,110.180.139.101,01/06/2021
```

This is my basic method that I wrote to read the file:

```
public static List<String> readDataLineByLine(String path, Class classModel) {
  try {
      Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(path));

      CsvToBean csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder(reader)
              .withType(classModel)
              .withSeparator(',')
              .withSkipLines(1)
              .withIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace(true)
              .build();

      List<String> results = csvToBean.parse();

      return results;
  } catch(IOException ex) {
      Log.error(ex.toString());
      return null;
  }
}
```

My model class:

```
public class MockarooFakeModel {

    @CsvBindByName(column = "id")
    private int ID;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "email")
    private String email;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "gender")
    private String gender;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "ip_address")
    private String IPAddress;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "date")
    private String date;

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getIPAddress() {
        return IPAddress;
    }

    public void setIPAddress(String IPAddress) {
        this.IPAddress = IPAddress;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        try {
            Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(this.date);
            return date;
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Log.error(ex.toString());
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

For some reason, when I debug the code, it returns 4 rows instead of 5 rows, and also it returns the rows with `null`. I thought it was because I didn't map the model, but that didn't fix the issue. Also, I don't think that TestNG causes some conflict when I execute the test.

```
@Test(description = "Gets the data stored in a CSV file")
public void Test4(Method method) {
    startTest(method.getName(),"Gets the data stored in a CSV file");

    var records = Utils.readDataLineByLine("PathToTheFile.csv", MockarooFakeModel.class);
}
```

[image]

I'll appreciate any help to solve my issue. Thanks!

**Update**

I forgot to check the checkbox to answer my own question, but I left here the solution to my problem (thanks, [@lastzolex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11544953/lastzolex)).-

I deleted `.withSkipLines()` and updated my reader method to return a `Class`:

```
public static List<Class> readDataLineByLine(String path, Class classModel) {
    try {
        Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(path));

        CsvToBean csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder(reader)
                .withType(classModel)
                .withSeparator(',')
                .withIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace(true)
                .build();

        List<Class> results = csvToBean.parse();

        return results;
    } catch(IOException ex) {
        Log.error(ex.toString());
        return null;
    }
}
```

[image]

I didn't know that `.withSkipLines()` skipped the line of data that I was sending (and the mapping I did do that automatically).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You described the problem very well, thanks for that!

In my opinion, the only problem is the line

```
.withSkipLines(1)
```

because you skip the header line while you are mapping with the headers at the same time. So the library is not able to match any value.

Just remove this from the lambda and you will get 5 lines of correctly mapped values.

Comment: just one more thing: your method reading the CSV should return 
    "List<MockarooFakeModel>"
instead of
    "List<String>"

Comment: It is better to edit your post to supplement.

Comment: thanks for the hint. I will do that in the future. 
To explain my intentions:  the comment is NOT anyway related to the stated problem, it is just another hint where to improve the code in general. so i chose the comment over the answer.

Comment: @LastZolex My idea is to use a generic method that uses any different kind of models, not only the one I'm passing it. How can I achieve that?

On the other hand, as you can see, I have 6 rows in my CSV file, and I'm skipping the header. Why it doesn't return the 5 rows, without counting the header?

Comment: ok, I understand. But then you are searching for quite a different solution than the one you sketched here... 
Just to sum it up again: the problem with the described aproach is that you use the header information to map the each line of the CSV to an object instance. This is done via the annotations  @CsvBindByName. But then you skip the header completely, so the library cannot map anything, because it is expecting the header to be in line 2 of the file...
What exactly is your expectation of what the line "csvToBean.parse()" should return?

Comment: @LastZolex Forget it, my bad. You're right. I modified my code, and also I'm returning an object of type Class and now it works. I'm going to update my question with the solution :)

Comment: good solution usinf generics! thanks for accepting my answer!